# Scrollable Panel snap to elements on Scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

Is there a way inside a scrollable div to snap to elements as the user scrolls.

For example if we have CSS such as

```
.container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto
}
li {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100 % ;
}
```

and HTML as

```
<div class="container">
    <li>
        test
    </li>
    <li>
        test
    </li>
    <li>
        test
    </li>
    <li>
        test
    </li>
    <li>
        test
    </li>
    <li>
        test
    </li>
    <li>
        test
    </li>
    <li>
        test
    </li>
    <li>
        test
    </li>
    <li>
        test
    </li>
    <li>
        test
    </li>
    <li>
        test
    </li>
    <li>
        test
    </li>
</div>
```

So from that the container should have a vertical scroll bar. When the user scrolls I would like it so that when they stop scrolling the final scroll position snaps the container scroll position to the nearest div at shown. This might be difficult as browsers like safari offer momentum as well, so it would have to be an event on scroll end.

Any ideas if this is possible, and how.

Marvellous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use setTimeout. This should work

```
var snap_timer;
var scroll_from_mouse = true;

function snapList(){
  var snapped = false;
  var i = 0;
  while(!snapped && i < $('.container li').size()){
    var itop = $('.container li').eq(i).position().top;
    var iheight = $('.container li').eq(i).outerHeight();
    if(itop < iheight && itop > 0){ 
      scroll_from_mouse = false;
      snapped = true;
      var new_scroll_top = 0;
      if(iheight - itop > iheight / 2)
        new_scroll_top = $('.container').scrollTop() + itop;
      else if(i > 1)
        new_scroll_top = $('.container').scrollTop() - ($('.container li').eq(i-1).outerHeight() - itop);
      else
        new_scroll_top = 0;
      $('.container').scrollTop(new_scroll_top);
    }
    i++;
  }
};

$(function(){
  $('.container').scroll(function(){
    clearTimeout(snap_timer);
    if(scroll_from_mouse) snap_timer = setTimeout(snapList, 200);
    scroll_from_mouse = true;
  });
});
```

Comment: Very nice. A bit jerky though. I am trying to replicate the way that it a select input works on the iPad and iPhone. That is although you can scroll it smoothly snaps to the internal elements. Your function is very good, do not get me wrong I am just being a perfectionist

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[CSS Scroll Snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap_Points)**.

However, the feature is now deprecated, so if you want to consider a cross-browser vanilla javascript re-implementation of the native CSS **Scroll Snap** spec, as already answered here: [How to emulate CSS Scroll Snap Points in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245252/how-to-emulate-css-scroll-snap-points-in-chrome/48683041#48683041), you can use

**[this library](https://github.com/lucafalasco/scroll-snap)** I wrote.

The main reason to use this instead of the native css solution is that it works in all modern browsers and has a customizable configuration to allow custom timing in transitions and scrolling detection.

The library re-implements the css snapping feature using vanilla javascript easing functions, and works using the values of the container element's `scrollTop`/`scrollLeft` properties and the *scroll* Event Listener

Here is an example that shows how to use it:

```
import createScrollSnap from 'scroll-snap'

const element = document.getElementById('container')

const { bind, unbind } = createScrollSnap(element, {
  snapDestinationX: '0%',
  snapDestinationY: '90%',
  timeout: 100,
  duration: 300,
  threshold: 0.2,
  snapStop: false,
  easing: easeInOutQuad,
}, () => console.log('snapped'))

// remove the listener 
// unbind();

// re-instantiate the listener 
// bind();
```

You can see a working demo **[here](https://lucafalasco.github.io/scroll-snap/)**

Comment: Please just note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please edit to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)