# How to emulate CSS Scroll Snap Points in Chrome?

Tags: css, polyfills

Firefox 39, Safari 9 and IE11 provide support for CSS Scroll Snap Points. Chrome has the feature [in development](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5721832506261504).

Is there a polyfill that would emulate the following CSS styles:

```
-webkit-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
-ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
-webkit-scroll-behavior: smooth;
-ms-scroll-behavior: smooth;
scroll-behavior: smooth;
-webkit-scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(600px);
-ms-scroll-snap-points-y: snapInterval(0px, 600px); /* Old syntax */
scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(600px);
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

until the feature is implemented by Chrome?

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind are plugins: [Scrollify](http://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#options), [panelSnap](http://guidobouman.github.io/jquery-panelsnap/) and [fullPage](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) .

Comment: like @dingo_d stated, you have to use one of the many plugins available or pure JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome 69 will contain [the feature](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5721832506261504). No workaround needed.

---

Just sit and wait. Just sit and wait :-)

Answer (score 6):

If you're willing to consider a **vanilla javascript re-implementation** of this feature with a consistent cross browser behaviour you can use

**[this library](https://github.com/lucafalasco/scroll-snap)**

#### **Why**

The main reason to use this instead of the native css solution is that it works in all modern browsers and has a customizable configuration to allow custom timing in transitions and scrolling detection.

#### **How**

The library re-implements the css snapping feature using vanilla javascript easing functions, and works using the values of the container element's `scrollTop`/`scrollLeft` properties and the *scroll* Event Listener

#### **Example**

```
import createScrollSnap from 'scroll-snap'

const element = document.getElementById('container')

const { bind, unbind } = createScrollSnap(element, {
  snapDestinationX: '0%',
  snapDestinationY: '90%',
  timeout: 100,
  duration: 300,
  threshold: 0.2,
  snapStop: false,
  easing: easeInOutQuad,
}, () => console.log('snapped'))

// remove the listener 
// unbind();

// re-instantiate the listener 
// bind();
```

Comment: Two days trying to making work this lib with no good results. I'm trying to use it inside a React stateless component. I see that the container div is modified by the lib (add the overflow:auto style) but then never call the callback with the scroll event.

Comment: hey @SantiagoBarchetta , [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/n2ynjj8lj?autoresize=1&hidenavigation=1) you can find an example usage of the library with React, in case it may help. Otherwise, I'm happy to help you debug the issue if you can provide a link with an example of your use case :)

Comment: Couldn't get the plugin to work with PX values or percentages that weren't integers

Comment: Hi @ESR , thanks for your feedback, pixel values as well as floating point numbers are supported starting from [v3.2.1](https://github.com/lucafalasco/scroll-snap/releases/tag/v3.2.1)

Answer (score 2):

I found a polyfill: https://github.com/zigotica/scrollSnapPointsPolyfill

Haven't tested it extensively.

Comment: it seems to depend on css classes to be implemented, that's not exactly a polyfill

Answer (score 2):

Here's another polyfill: https://github.com/ckrack/scrollsnap-polyfill/

It should also be noted that the specification for [CSS Snap Points](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-snappoints/) has changed and no longer includes some of the properties asked for, as well as adding new ones.

Comment: I believe it doesn't work with pixel units, only vh or %

Comment: @davidtaubmann you must've missed that the [scrollsnap-polyfill documentation](https://github.com/ckrack/scrollsnap-polyfill/#limitations) says that it works with `vh/vw`, `percentages`, and `pixels`.

Comment: After testing a lot, it never worked with pixels. All the examples found that where correctly working stopped working once I changed the CSS values to pixels. If you have a working example that's focused on pixels, I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Very poor working of this stuff on this moment, scrolling on Google works only with **ovrflow:auto** container property correctly for **scroll-snap-align** property of items and **scroll padding** property for each item in container.

[https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-scroll-snap-using-css--cms-30333][1]